# Is there a way to develop app with fork on windows then packaging to .exe

Tags: python, windows, fork, system-calls

I want to develop gui app with python tkinter on windows.
I want to use `fork` system call. But windows does not support `fork`

Then its app packaging as .exe file with pyinstaller.

Is there any way to use fork on windows?
I suppose to use mingw or cygwin but I do not know how I do compile python and create windows .exe file on these environment.

I am using:
Python 3.6.4
Windows10 1709

Comment: The Windows kernel supports forking (e.g. for the old POSIX subsystem and the new Linux subsystem in Windows 10), but the Windows API does not. The Cygwin environment emulates it with multiple system calls, but this is expensive. Using Windows Python, you can simply spawn a new process via `subprocess.Popen`.

Comment: Is Windows Subsystem for Linux is useful to solve my problem?

Comment: No, WSL is only for console and command-line applications, not GUI apps.